# About solr query facet

Tags: java, solr

In my solr document, the document data is like:

```
  {
    "createTime":"2013-09-10",
    "reason":"reason1",
    "postId":"postId_1",
    "_version_":1445959401549594624 },
  {
    "createTime":"2013-09-11",
    "reason":"reason2",
    "postId":"postId_1",
    "_version_":1445959401549594624 },
  {
    "createTime":"2013-09-12",
    "reason":"reason3",
    "postId":"postId_1",
    "_version_":1445959401549594624 },
  {
    "createTime":"2013-09-13",
    "reason":"reason4",
    "postId":"postId_2",
    "_version_":1445959401549594624 },<script>alert("1")</script>
```

Now I need use solr facetQuery to select some data like this:

```
     1. postId1, 3 records, the last createTime is "2013-09-12"
     2. postId2, 1 record, the last createTime is "2013-09-13", reason is reason4
```

How can I do this using solr facetQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Field Collapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) feature, which can help you group the results.
If you group on post_id, you would be able to get the the results as per the post id.
You would get the count for each post id (`numFound`), which will give you the `3 records` part.
You can order the results within the group by date desc and return single result (`group.limit=1`) which will give you the last date.
You can pick up the `reason` from the records.